# How to get expected link from same named link on Web Page?

Tags: c#, html, selenium, xpath, automation

I am using  Selenium with C# for doing automation of Web Page. I wanted to click on link named *Edit*.

I used following code to click on Edit,

```
driver.FindElementByPartialLinkText("Edit").Click();
```

Now, problem is my page has multiple links named *Edit*, I have attached following screen shot for more clarity.

I wanted to click link which is in table. I tried to copy XPath using Chrome Developer tool, but it is very specific, I may get more rows in table, so it will not be generic solution.

I got distinguished **title** (not text), can I used it with XPath?

[image: You can see multiple edits]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a list of the web elements and then filter based on the title text. Something like this should workd

```
List <WebElement> list= driver.findElements(By.linkText ( text ) );
```

and then iterate the list of element and look for the title u are looking for using

```
if (element.getAttribute("title").equals("Something")
     //Do something
```

and perform the action based on that.